# How to add fields that dinamically change values in binded variables

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In order to explain my problem let's say I have in my ViewModel an ObservableCollection which has several elements of my type Item defined in my Models. These items as in any other shop have a name and a price and are all listed in one of my views.

My question is if there is any way to create variables to alter, for example, the price of each item dynamically. What I would like to do is: for each element in my listView, have one or more entries to allow me to customize his characteristics. Let's say that the user enters the value 2 in one of this entries, the price of the item corresponding to that line of the listView should be 2x higher but the others must remain the same.

To make it a practical example, take into consideration the following image. Let's say the first line is the name of the product and the second line is the price, I would like to have, in each row, at least one entry to allow me to customize the value of the price. Is it possible?

[Article List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSS9T.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new property to bind to Label.Text, and update it when the property bound to the Entry.Text property changes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is indeed what I aim to do, but would it work for each element in my list view separetely? My listview will be populated from my viewModel with Item objects and I would have na Entry for each label with each Item's price...I fear that if I do this once I change on entry it will update all the other item's prices.

Comment: As long as each item's ViewModel has its own "multiplier" property it shouldn't affect the other rows.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
you can add the Entry to your ViewCell, and bind the Entry to the same property you bind to the Label. When you change the value in the Entry, the value in the Label should change.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but that way I would have to write the exact value to change the value of the label, let's say I would want the value 300, I would write 300 in the entry. I don't want that. I would like to have the value 150 in the label and type in 2 in the entry to make it 300 for example. In this case I can't bind it to the same property. I hope I made myself clear this time. Oh and this entries had to be added to each element in the list view because I want to add different values for different products....

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the simplest way to achieve this is to wrap each `Item` in an `ItemViewModel`.

The `ItemViewModel` has a public Property `Multiplier` where - in the Setter - the price of the containing `Item` will be updated.

For the price change to be reflected in the view - it must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and of course raise the event when the 'Price' is set.

Alternatively: copy the `Price` from the `Item` to the `ItemViewModel` in the constructor to an additional `Price` property on the `ItemViewModel`

With the sample code you'd need a IValueConverter to convert the Entry Text from `string` to `double` (or use an apropriate control that allows binding to `double`)

```
public class ItemsViewModel
{

    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }

    public ItemsViewModel()
    {
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>(getItemsFromSomewhere().Select(item => new ItemViewModel(item)));
    }

}

public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private readonly Item item;
    private double price;
    private double multiplicator;

    public ItemViewModel(Item item)
    {
        this.item = item;
        this.price = item.Price;
    }

    public double Multiplicator {
        get { return this.multiplicator; }
        set {
            this.multiplicator = value;
            this.Price = this.item.Price * value;
        }
    }

    public double Price {
        get { return this.price; }
        set {
            this.price = value; 
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}

public class Item
{

    public double Price { get; set; }

}
```